# Creating the right Database table structure for address change + pricing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm a little stumped on whether i can make this process of changing addresses easier. I'll explain the situation:

Basically I have three entities, Students, Addresses, StudentsAddresses. Students have many addresses, since they can change alot and rapidly (especially foster kids / homeless kids). So ill be changing them a lot. However based on each address I Want a user to attach (enter it via the UI) the price it would cost to pick that student up via bus service. So my initial thought was, ok, let me attach a column onto my join table 'StudentsAddresses' called 'dailyPrice', this is the cost for each day a student is picked up, and another column called 'adjustmentPrice', which is an additional cost for whatever special circumstance that requires extra work to pick up a student. Is my thinking going to cause me problems the more students I have in the future? Will it get harder to manage?

Another option I thought about, was creating a new Table called Pricing. And another join-type table called **StudentsAddressesPricing**
StudentsAddressPricing has three columns,

```
studentId 
addressId 
pricingId
```

each field connects the three together. So if i ever needed Students, with their addresses, and the pricing, i would query this table and eager load Students, Addresses, and Pricing. Does this approach seem much cleaner since i've abstracted pricing out a bit? Trying to determine the best way to go about this without having to many headaches in the future incase I wan't to add more attributes pricing related, or address related.

And then I even thought, hey what if pricing is just different for one day? How would I even consider that. Would I need a different kind of entity to handle that? Is doing alot of joins going to hurt my application performance?

**Just looking for some insight on how others would do it, and criticism on why im off the ball.**

Comment: Well in my opinion you need another table which will be transnational type. So when the user inputs any data it goes into this table along with the keys of student, address .

Answer (score 2):

The main question you should ask yourself is: on what does the price depend?

If the price is determined by the address, you might as well add it to `addresses`. If the price also depends on the student (e.g., depending on their financial situation), it would make sense to put it into `studentsaddresses`.

In other words: The table where the price is stored should have foreign keys to everything outside the table that determines the price. If that makes it fit into one of the existing tables, keep it there.

Comment: Thanks, this was pretty clarifying and sensible. I made some changes to the way things work (decoupling addresses and pricing in the app logic) but this answer was still relevant.